# WinRT app - what data about user I can get?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, runtime

I want to create an app (for Windows runtime), that will get data about user preferences, history of downloaded apps and so on. I want to gather that data and analise it to create some kind of App Advisor.

So: Can I get data like installed apps or something of that sort?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of from a Windows Store app. You can get some of it through [Windows.Management.Deployment APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.management.deployment.aspx), but those are restricted to full-trust processes and thus have to be used from a desktop/Win32 application.